# Sony Vaio laptop LCD developed a black fish/feather shape inside the screen

Tags: lcd, sony-vaio

My Vaio, which I've had for a while, now has a black "fish" or oval splotch in the screen.

[image: Vaio Screen]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Dear your screen is broken. Please see carefully in the middle of the fish, it has a backbone (crack). The same happened with mine without any cause and gradually spread end to end until I replaced it.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the cause of placing your laptop too close to magnetic sources such as magnets. Looking at the picture, the pixels are discolored and damaged from within the screen itself. Or it could be a faulty defect with your laptop. I suggest taking this to warranty as this is well within what warranty can recover and replace.

Comment: warranty has long expired, fixing for a friend. thinking a new LCD panel should do it.

Comment: LCD screens are not damaged by magnetic fields the way CRT screens are (also, CRT screens may actually be demagnetized with either the appropriate tools, or another small magnet and lots of patience). This is the crystal matrix broken by a hit or by a weight on the closed laptop.